# Bukkit/JavaPlugin - Setting outcome for existing crafting recipe not working

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm new to  Plugin Development for Bukkit

For my private Minecraft Server I want to add/change crafting recipes. I want to craft SlimeBlocks with just 4 SlimeBalls so here is what I got:

```
 @Override
public void onEnable() {

    ItemStack slimeBlockStack = new ItemStack(Material.SLIME_BLOCK);
    ShapedRecipe slimeBlockRecipe = new ShapedRecipe(slimeBlockStack);

    slimeBlockRecipe.shape("###", "#oo", "#oo");
    slimeBlockRecipe.setIngredient('o', Material.SLIME_BALL);
    slimeBlockRecipe.setIngredient('#', Material.AIR);

    getServer().addRecipe(slimeBlockRecipe);

//....here comes more   
}
```

Now so you cannot "cheat" slimeballs by crafting blocks with 4 and then crafting it back to 9 slimeballs I want to override the outcome of the existing crafting recipe - I tried to Iterate over a List with all Recipes and then setting the amount of the result, but it is not working...

```
Iterator<Recipe> it = Bukkit.getServer().recipeIterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        ItemStack result = it.next().getResult();
        if(result.isSimilar(new ItemStack(Material.SLIME_BALL))) {

            result.setAmount(4);

        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong, I apreciate every help/hint

Comment: Any errors / what does console say?

Comment: Just by a quick look, `Bukket.getServer().recipeIterator()` is probably read-only.

Comment: @MCMastery no no Errors no Warnings, if i log the emount of the result it shows me the correct value, but in Minecraft nothing changes. I dont think its read only because then setAmount would throw and Error/Warning?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by changing some things...
Shapedrecipe only gives a clone/copy of the Recipe and not the actual one.
I used the PrepareItemCraftEvent to change the outcome if a player wants to craft something:

```
public class MyListener implements Listener {

@EventHandler
public void craftEvent(PrepareItemCraftEvent event) {
    ItemStack[] contents = event.getInventory().getContents();
    ItemStack firstInContents = contents[0];

    if((firstInContents.getType()==Material.SLIME_BALL) && (firstInContents.getAmount() == 9)) {
        firstInContents.setAmount(4);
    }

}
}
```

in the onEnable method I registered my Listener
`getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MyListener(), this);`